# I want my pages to find their asstes (css, scripts, etc.) in the current folder instead of the root, how?

Tags: .htaccess

I just managed to autodeplay my GitHub repositories to http://github.mydomain.com/repositoryname.

Now the following: most of my projects have their stylesheets, javascripts etc. folders in the root, so like href="/css/styles.css" and src="/js/scripts.js". I want these to redirect/-write to href="/repositoryname/css/styles.css" and src="/repositoryname/js/scripts.js".

I have no to little experience with htaccess so I hope someone will help me out!

Thanks,
Iason

Answer (score 0):

why don't use relative path rather then absolute pat.This help you to run project any were in directory .

Eg:- ./js/myscript.js etc .

Comment: Totally true, but there any many repos and directory structures. That will cost me some time. I need a less time consuming solution for the time being. I'll take your advice for the coming projects, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
We redirect the URL / to /about/:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/$  /about/  [R]

Note that this can also be handled using the RedirectMatch directive:

RedirectMatch ^/$ http://example.com/about/

Note also that the example rewrites only the root URL. That is, it rewrites a request for http://example.com/, but not a request for http://example.com/page.html. If you have in fact changed your document root - that is, if all of your content is in fact in that subdirectory, it is greatly preferable to simply change your DocumentRoot directive, or move all of the content up one directory, rather than rewriting URLs.
```

This a solution taken from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#page-header see Moved DocumentRoot heading.

Comment: Thanks! Just one thing.. Is it possible to use a 'variable' for the /about/ part as used in your example? I want /about/ to be like /[respositoryname]/ so this htaccess can be used generic for all projects. The repositoryname is always the first folder, for example: http://github.mydomain.com/[repositoryname]/news/archive